# Expected value in usual quantum mechanics vs quantum information

Tags: quantum-information, phase-space, quantum-measurements, open-quantum-systems

In standard Quantum Mechanics, one computes the expected value of an operator $A$ (arbitrary state $|\Psi\rangle$) as

$$
\langle\Psi|A|\Psi\rangle.
$$

This has the virtue that we can compute for instance the average energy of the system $E=\langle \Psi|H|\Psi\rangle$ and also we can compute, if we want, the expected value of non-Hermitian operators like $\alpha = \langle \Psi|a|\Psi\rangle$ in the Harmonic oscillator. Now, in Quantum Information or Quantum Open Systems, one usually works with a complete set of *measurement* (Kraus) operators $\{ K_m\}$ that fulfill

$$
\sum_m K^\dagger_m K_m=\mathbb{I}.
$$

Then, for instance, the majority of quantities that we can measure (if not all) will be Hermitian, since for instance

$$
\langle\Psi|a^\dagger a|\Psi\rangle.
$$

On the other hand, as it is true that e.g. $a$ is not a Hermitian operator, in phase space techniques one manipulates such quantities theoretically and they are very useful for studying the system dynamics.

My questions are: can the set of measurement operators $\lbrace K_m\rbrace$ can at some point accommodate such non-Hermitian quantities? Why have a formalism that in principle "loses" a big amount of (theoretically) useful information?

Answer (score 3):

You can measure the expectation value of any operator $O$ if you can measure hermitian operators, by decomposing it as
$$
O=H+iA\ ,
$$
where $H=(O+O^\dagger)/2$ and A=$(O-O^\dagger)/2i$ are both hermitian,
and measuring the expectation value of $H$ and $A$ individually.

Thus, any measurement formalism which allows you to measure hermitian observables allows you to measure *any* observable.

In particular, for the POVM measurement formalism you describe above (what you term "Kraus operators"), given the eigenvalue decompositions of $H$ and $A$,
$$
H=\sum_{i=1}^n h_i|H_i\rangle\langle H_i|\,,\ 
A=\sum_{i=1}^n a_i|A_i\rangle\langle A_i|\,,
$$
you can define a POVM measurement with operators
$$\{K_k\}=\{\tfrac{1}{\sqrt{2}}|H_1\rangle\langle H_1|,\ldots,\tfrac{1}{\sqrt{2}}|H_n\rangle\langle H_n|,
\tfrac{1}{\sqrt{2}}|A_1\rangle\langle A_1|,\ldots,\tfrac{1}{\sqrt{2}}|A_n\rangle\langle A_n|\}\ .
$$
Given the outcome probabilities $p_k$, you can then compute $\langle O\rangle$ as
$$
\langle O \rangle = \sum_{k=1}^n (p_k h_k + i p_{k+n} a_k)\ .
$$

Finally, note that whenever $O$ is unitarily diagonalizable (but not necessarily hermitian - namely, this holds if and only if $O$ is normal), you can compute $\langle O\rangle$ by defining POVM operators $K_k$ as the projectors onto the eigenvectors of $O$, as above.

Comment: What if H and A don't commute?

Comment: @PeterA To measure expectation values you have to measure repeatedly anyway. So now you measure H repeatedly and A repeatedly (but separately).